# Have a JSON file on server with a Array of objects and want to push an object to it with fs.appendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this JSON on server: `[{"a":1}, {"a":2}]` and wonder if there is anyway to add a object in the end, instead if rewrite whole file on server. I have make the workaround, whitout brackets and add them after a load from server.

```
newObj=  {'a':3};  
fs.appendFile(theServerFile, ',' + newObj, ...) ;
```

Comment: In a word, No. the entire JSON will have to be read, parsed, updated and written back to the file. Doing otherwise will likely produce invalid JSON

Comment: Editing JSON data in string is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Not to mention your file locking issues.

Answer (score -1):

I would would do the following:

```
    const fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile('./jsonFile.html', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
             throw err;
        }

        processFile( JSON.parse(data) );        
     });

     function processFile(data) {
         data.push(newObj);
         fs.writeFileSync('./jsonFile.html', data);
     }
```

Retrieve the current content, update it and write it again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: there are two problems in your answer, 1. you have to parse the file data into JSON object before processing. 2. if you append data to the original file like this, it will append second set of data to the original file

Comment: Your code is appending the updated JSON to the file instead of overwriting it

Comment: well, now you didn't answer the original question about using `fs.appendFile` :)